# Convert "_" to " " when selecting column names in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query.

```
select COLUMN_NAME as Name
FROM            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE        (TABLE_NAME = 'IM_NOTES')
```

and the result is

```
Name
ID
ORGANIZATION_ID
SITE_ID
INCIDENT_ID
NOTES_CATEGORY_ID
PUBLISH_TO_SELF_SERVICE
ESTIMATED_EFFORTS
NOTE_SUMMARY
NOTE_DESCRIPTION
CREATED_BY
CREATED_DATE
MODIFIED_BY
MODIFIED_DATE
MODE_ID
SEQUENCE_NUMBER
PARENT_TYPE
```

I need to convert all the '_' in the output to ' '. How to achieve that?

Comment: Changing to `-` will make for illegal field names. you'd have to quote ALL of them, because `select modified-by` will simply be seen as "select the value of `by` subtracted from `modified`.

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't. Also, don't do this.

Comment: You want to change the column names, or you just want the output of that query to return spaces instead of _ ?

Comment: Actually I need the column names in some other place without under scores(_). that is why i am asking. I dont need to change the column names @MarcB

Comment: @user3095901. Is this mysql?

Comment: No i dont want to change the column names. just want the output of that query to return spaces instead of _ . @FilipeSilva

Comment: In SQL SERVER @FilipeSilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should avoid adding spaces to column names, But if you only want to get the column names with spaces instead of _ , you can use the [REPLACE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '_', ' ') AS Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'IM_NOTES')
```